# How do I calculate the shortest counter-clockwise angle to the closest incision made in an evenly-cut 2D plane?

Tags: trigonometry

I regularly use the equation $\operatorname{atan2}(\sin(k),\cos(k))$ to wrap an arbitrary angle $k$ to the range $[-\pi, +\pi)$. I think of this as expressing it counter-clockwise with respect to the $+x$ axis of the Cartesian plane. What if I instead wished to express the counter-clockwise angle with respect to the nearest of the four axes $+x, +y, -x, -y$ in the Cartesian plane? In this case the resulting angle should be in the range $[-\pi/4, +\pi/4)$. More generally, if I was to rotationally divide the Cartesian plane evenly into N angular slices, with the first cut being along $+x$ axis, is there a way to calculate the counter-clockwise signed distance to the nearest incision in the range $[-\pi/N, +\pi/N)$? I realize that this can probably be done programmatically with iterations and conditionals. I after the elegant trigonometric solution, assuming one exists  :)

Comment: Use dollar signs to write mathematical expressions.

Comment: Thanks, @vitamind!

Answer (score 1):

The points $e^{2ik\pi}$  for $k= 0, \ldots , n-1$ divide the circle into the $n$ equal segments you want. So find the value of $k$ that minimizes the distance from your angle to $2k\pi$.

Then use Euler's formula to get the Cartesian coordinates and the Euclidean distance.

Comment: Thanks, Ethan. I think that I understand your solution, but in practice it will involve iterating over $k$ to find the nearest segment boundary point to  which the signed distance can be calculated. I had hoped there might be single elegant trigonometric formula. For example, something like $atan2(sin(Nk),cos(Nk))/N$ (which I have tested and realize doesn't work).

Comment: I doubt that you can do this with a single formula. But finding out which subdivision of the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ contains your angle is probably not too expensive. If I needed this in a program I would just code it naively and optimize later if it turned out to be necessary.